# Regex String for allowing 1 character and blank space

Tags: c#, regex, validation

A field needs validation to only be able to contain `(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H)` or blank

Is anybody sure on a regex for this validation?

Currently have this: `^[A-Ha-h]{1}$`

Answer (score 6):

Just a simple change:

```
 ^[A-Ha-h]?$
          ^
```

This makes it optional to input the character, thus allowing you to input blank.

Comment: Good spot, seems likely that OP doesn't want to match an actual space character

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks, that what I assumed since he didn't type `space` but `blank`.

Answer (score 2):

If by 'blank space' you mean a literal space character, try this:

```
^[A-Ha-h ]$
```

Or use the the [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and simplify this to

```
^[A-H ]$
```

On the other hand, if by 'blank space' you mean an empty string, try this:

```
^[A-Ha-h]?$
```

Or with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
^[A-H]?$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern

```
@"^(?i)[a-h\s]$"
```

- `(?i) - Ignore case`
- `a-h  - A-H, a-h`
- `\s   - matches white space`